# Exception - Unable to set property userLogin for managed bean credentials

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, session-scope

For authentication purposes, I am injecting a request scoped backing bean into another session scoped bean that is going to store the logged user. Or at least it should... 
Following , a bit of code:

**Request scoped bean - managed property**

```
@ManagedProperty(value="userLogin")
```

**Error**
*Unable to set property userLogin for managed bean credentials*

**Stack trace**

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property userLogin for managed bean credentials
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:615)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert userLogin of type class java.lang.String to class model.businessLogic.UserLogin
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:420)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.coerce(ELUtils.java:536)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(BeanBuilder.java:592)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:606)
... 51 more
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read the exception's root cause to understand the cause (and inherently thus also the  solution):

> Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert userLogin of type class java.lang.String to class model.businessLogic.UserLogin

Thus, you were referencing a `String` instance as a managed bean instead of `UserLogin` instance.

And indeed, your managed property value is invalid:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="userLogin")
```

It references a plain vanilla `String`. You need to reference a managed bean instead:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userLogin}")
```

Or, shorter, as the `value` attribtue is the annotation's default attribute:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{userLogin}")
```

Comment: I did read the stack trace and I noticed that line but wasn't obviously looking right. For my eyes it was ok :P .Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, you must clean the spaces too, for example:

this is OK:
`@ManagedProperty(value="#{userLogin}")`

this is NOT OK, the app doesn't work if you do that
`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{userLogin}")`